# Turn off part of Application Layout with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've created a side menu in the layout application but i don't wanna show it on the sign in page, but i wanna see the rest of layout application .

this is the part that i don't wanna show in sign in page.

```
<% if is_a?(Devise::SessionsController) %>
  <div class="col-sm-3" style = "position: relative;">
      <!-- left -->
      <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Menu</h3>
      <hr>

      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Pesquisar</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i> Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> Real-time</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicons-heart"></i> Advanced..</a></li>
      </ul>

      <hr>

    </div><!-- /span-3 -->
```

but this command shutoff this part of the code in all of my pages, so how do i specify that is just my users/sign_in page?

Comment: Is this Rails 4 or an earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide portions of the UI described by your `layouts/application.html.erb` file by testing for the controller and action.

In Rails 4, you have access to the `controller_name` and `action_name` helpers in your views. You can add logic to your `application.html.erb` as follows:

```
<% !(if controller_name == 'devise/sessions' && action_name == 'new') %>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style = "position: relative;">
      <!-- left -->
      <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Menu</h3>
      <hr>

      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Pesquisar</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i> Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> Real-time</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicons-heart"></i> Advanced..</a></li>
      </ul>

      <hr>

    </div>
<% end %>
```

Your sidebar should render for anything other than the Devise sign in page.

Another approach would be to move the elements of `application.html.erb` that you want to your sign-in page and use:

`render :layout => false`

in your controller to suppress stuff from your layouts directory.

Comment: i didn't expressed well, i don't wanna see this part of code , in my page of sign in , doesn't matter if the user is signed_in or not.

Comment: Sorry, you expressed it correctly -- I just didn't read closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to show this part only to logged-in users. So this is, what you could do:

In your controller there should be a current_user. So replace

```
<% if is_a?(Devise::SessionsController) %>
```

with

```
<% if !current_user %>
```

Basically this should be already done in the controller and then the right view chosen. But it might help for now.

Comment: i didn't expressed well, i don't wanna see this part of code , in my page of sign in , doesn't matter if the user is signed_in or not.

Comment: Can you say what exactly the condition for this part of code is? If you don't  want to see it, there is always the possibility to simply delete it!